# StreamSets - How to bind variable for oracle jdbc producer

Tags: streamsets

We are having a requirement to use oracle bind variable to run any queries onto oracle Database, by that it will do soft parsing rather than hard parsing to improve the performance. I have checked but didn't find anything , Please help if it is feasible in StreamSets.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution-

StreanSets internally uses bind variables when we use oracle jdbc producer to publish records. Enable debug mode to see queries generated by streamsets which are being fired on oracle db.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and posting the solution!